# Register joined/abandoned in og group

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, organic-groups

I need register in a custom log when a user requests to join a group. Then I need register that the user has joined in the group or has abandoned this.

I do not know how to do it without changing the orginal module. I do not know how I can extend the functionality of a contributed module correctly.

Appreciate any guidance to investigate. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use module [rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules)
Event to trigger rule:

```
OG member subscribe (Active): rules_og_member_active
OG member subscribe (Pending): rules_og_member_pending
OG member subscribe (Blocked): rules_og_member_blocked
OG member denied (Deny) :rules_og_member_denied_deny_
```